# Using javascript to assign a php variable

Tags: php, javascript, html, codeigniter

I purchased modalbox plugin from envato market place made in javascript i want to use it to implement my categories> subcategories> items. Anyhow i know JavaScript variable can be assigned a value using php however i need the opposite.

On my first step i let the user pick a category using basic links then onclick even takes them to second slide where i want to display the subcategories and items related to this category that was selected.

I tried two things:

```
1) setting onClick = "step2();<?php $chosen_cat = ' . $this->db->escape(trim($category)) . '?>"
```

Hoping i can simply assign the name of the selected category to a value and then just use $chosen_cat in step2() javascript method to display products however this breaks the javascript as there is a conflict in output;

> 2) I changed step2() to step2(category) and then used,
>   onclick="step2(db->escape($category););"  this passes the
>   value to the step2() method however now i would need to call  <-- I would need to print out
>   that string to php however i have no idea how to solve this
>   considering PHP -> JS is viable as its server to client relation but
>   back..

The $this->db->escape() is a http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html codeigniter method.

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function step1() {
            modalbox.show(new Element("div").insert(
                new Element("p", { "align": "justify" }).insert(
                    <?php 
                        $categories = $items;
                        $chosen_cat = '';
                    ?>
                    <?php 
                        $i = 0;
                        foreach($categories as $category => $itemarray) {
                            $i++;
                            if($i==27){
                                echo  $this->db->escape('<a class="category" onclick="step2();<?php $chosen_cat = ' . $this->db->escape(trim($category)) . '?>" href="#">'. trim($category) . '</a>');
                            }
                            else {
                                echo $this->db->escape('<a class="category" onclick="step2();" href="#">' . trim($category) . '</a>')  . '+';
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                )
            ), {
                "title"     : "Step 1/3",
                "width"     : 800,
                "options"   : [{
                    "label"     : "Next »",
                    "onClick"   : step2
                }]
            });
        };

        function step2() {
            alert(<?php $this->db->escape($chosen_cat); ?>);
            modalbox.show([ new Element("div").insert(
                new Element("p", { "align": "justify" }).insert(
                    "If you open a modalbox when another one is opened, it will stretch to the new " +
                    "modalbox width and height and overwrite the content.<br /\><br /\>" +
                    "You can use HTML or Prototype Elements like a DIV or a TABLE."
                )
            ),
                new Element("p", { "align": "justify" }).insert(
                    "You can have multiple contents on a single modalbox by using an array like this:<br /\><br /\>" +
                    "<pre>modalbox.show([ content1, content2, ... ], options);</pre>"
                )
            ], {
                "title"     : "Step 2/3",
                "width"     : 800,
                "options"   : [{
                    "label"     : "« Previous",
                    "onClick"   : step1
                }, {
                    "label"     : "Next »",
                    "onClick"   : step3
                }]
            }); 
        };
        function step3() {
            modalbox.show([ new Element("div").insert(
                new Element("p", { "align": "justify" }).insert(
                    "If you open a modalbox when another one is opened, it will stretch to the new " +
                    "modalbox width and height and overwrite the content.<br /\><br /\>" +
                    "You can use HTML or Prototype Elements like a DIV or a TABLE."
                )
            ),
                new Element("p", { "align": "justify" }).insert(
                    "You can have multiple contents on a single modalbox by using an array like this:<br /\><br /\>" +
                    "<pre>modalbox.show([ content1, content2, ... ], options);</pre>"
                )
            ], {
                "title"     : "Step 3/3",
                "width"     : 800,
                "hideOnPageClick": false,
                "options"   : [{
                    "label"     : "« Previous",
                    "onClick"   : step2
                }, {
                    "label"     : "Finish",
                    "isDefault" : true,
                    "onClick"   : modalbox.hide
                }]
            });
        };

    </script>
```

Would it be possible to set a session variable with JavaScript in the onclick event say $_SESSION['category'] = 'category' in js style and then read that session with php and unset it i dont think this would create much of a security problem as session would exist for prolly less than a second.

Comment: PHP happens on the server side. Javascript happens on the client side. You *can't* output executable PHP from javascript. It's impossible. You can use AJAX to achieve the effect you want, or pre-populate the javascript with all the data you need.

Comment: The code sample you have is calling `$this->db->escape('<a class="category" onclick="step2()` on hardcoded HTML, that doesn't make sense, why are you db escaping HTML? I'm pretty sure the escape is for protecting against SQL injection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript is never going to set a PHP variable. JavaScript runs on the client and PHP on the server. If you need to change something on the server from JS, you have to use AJAX, or send a regular HTTP request.

Alternatively, you can have PHP generate the data that is needed at runtime on the client, usually by printing some JSON to become a JS variable

In your example, you would need something like the following (I'll use jQuery for simplicity)

```
... onclick="$.ajax('/category.php').done(function(data) {step2(data.category);})"
```

Which would be much nicer if it weren't JS within HTML

```
$('#my-button').click(function(){
    $.ajax('/category.php').done(function(data) {
        step2(data.category);
    });
});
```

I can't give you an AJAX tutorial, but the main thing is that you'll make an AJAX request when you need data from the server.

Comment: I have never used AJAX will this effect my code a lot ? On the other side would a temporary session be possible if js can create those ?

Comment: Yes it will affect your code a lot. Let me put in a small example.

Comment: Will this refresh the page if so then it's not really useful. Would it be possible to just call php on onclick event as well as i tried or could i maybe use onclick to call the javascript:step2() method and along also call ajax that would set a session variable which i could then just read with php ?

Comment: @kellax Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. The code I wrote is not going to refresh the page. The AJAX call can set a session variable without refreshing the page. You should read some AJAX tutorials and understand the "wall of separation between client side JS and PHP"

Comment: Oke i need to learn how to use ajax called from onclick to set a session then i can read it from php think this will be the best and simplest solution i hope.