# how to get javascript return value to php variable?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have created a javascript for check the text boxes are empty. if one of text box is empty the return false. so how can i get that return value to a PHP variable ?

Comment: Use ajax, or just submit the form. THat is after all what fors are for

Comment: POST the data, either Jquery or HTTP

Comment: For assigning js variable to php you can refer here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978927/using-javascript-to-assign-a-php-variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For linking javascript with php need to use AJAX http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to assign return value in same page

```
<script language="javascript" >
  var id = "data"
</script>

<?php
   $getthevalueofid = var id;
 ?>
```

**or use this line in submit button to posting the result to another page**

result = your validation result

```
window.location.href="index.php?uid=result";
```

Call this in Another page to Get the return result

```
$somevar = $_GET["uid"]; //puts the uid varialbe into $somevar
```

Comment: Ar you sure that `$getthevalueofid = var id;` works ?

Answer (score 0):

Do either form submit or url redirect with parameters, or ajax request to your php script and if your url query was `?foo=bar`, then in your PHP you can get it like this:

```
<?
    $foo = $_REQUEST['foo']; // bar
?>
```

Comment: how var id could work in php